# Resize/reposition Microsoft Visio 2013 Shapes, On Different Pages?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

How might I efficiently resize/reposition Microsoft Visio 2013 shapes, across different pages? Is editing them one-by-one the only way?

For example, I have 28 pages, each with a text box which I want to have the same x/y position and height/width.

I tried selecting the object, on page 1, selecting format painter, then applying it to the object, on page 2, but that failed to resize/reposition.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved via a Macro, which performed five steps (assuming Size & Position Task Pane showing):

1. Select the Shape
2. In Task Pane Size & Position, resize x
3. In Task Pane Size & Position, resize y
4. In Task Pane Size & Position, resize width
5. In Task Pane Size & Position, resize height

Additional details, via Microsoft https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-macros-in-Visio-05c29ac5-922d-4fd4-8d60-8e2ccd3ecc5a :

> On the Developer tab, click Record Macro. (If you don’t see the
>   Developer tab, see “Show the Developer tab” below.)
>
> Macros commands
>
> In the Macro name box, type a name for the macro.
>
> In the Shortcut key box, type a shortcut key that can be used with the
>   CTRL key to run the macro.
>
> In the Store macro in box, click the document in which you want to
>   store the macro.
>
> In the Description box, type a description for the macro.
>
> Click OK to begin recording the macro.
>
> Perform the actions you want to include in your macro. On the
>   Developer tab, use Pause Recording if needed.
>
> When you record a macro, you can use the mouse to click commands and
>   options, and to work with shapes and objects in drawings.
>
> To stop recording your macro, click Stop Recording on the Developer
>   tab.
>
> You can also pause or resume macro recording using the Recording
>   toolbar.
>
> To view the resulting code, on the Tools menu, point to Macros, click
>   Macros, click the macro name, and then click Edit.
>
> SHOW THE DEVELOPER TAB
>
> Click the File tab and then click Options.
>
> Click Customize Ribbon.
>
> Under Customize the Ribbon and under Main Tabs, select the Developer
>   check box.
>
> The Developer tab appears at the end of the ribbon opposite the File
>   tab.